# recovery user ID with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

I have a problem with my redirection.
I would like to redirect my user if it is new to my registerscreen, if not new to my topnavigationscreen.

To check if the user exists I would like to get some information from "cloud firestore" which is created in my registerscreen.
But I can't get them back.

My little code:

```
 void registergoogleUser() async {
    await _userProvider
        .registergoogleUser( _scaffoldKey)
        .then((response) async {
      if (response is Success<UserCredential>) {
        Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUser(String userId) async {
          final FirebaseFirestore instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
          print (await instance.collection('users')?.doc(userId)?.get());// for test
          (await instance.collection('users')?.doc(userId)?.get());
        }
        print (getUser);
        if (await getUser != null) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              TopNavigationScreen.id, (route) => false);
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, RegisterScreen.id);
        }
        }});
  }
```

But my "run" return this:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

and my

```
print (instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get());
```

return this:

> I/flutter (25671): Closure: (String) => Future

you can see my code (for variables and other) here:

Answer (score 1):

Here

```dart
print(await instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get())
```

you are using Future as synchronous call. You must `await` for value then if docs not null use `get` on it. By the way in cases like this use `?.` operator to be null-safe, like

```dart
print(await instance.collection('users')?.doc(userId)?.get())
```

Comment: Hello Simon Sot, i modified my code: in my answer but my "run" return: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Comment: Try to place `await` before instance.collection('users')?.doc(userId)?.get() inside `fetUser` function

Comment: Simon Sot, i add await and async, but my "run" return same error... thank for help, i have modified my answer.

Comment: getUser(String userId), but have you passed `userId` when you call this function? Use `getUser(response.user.uid)`

Comment: yes I think the problem comes from "userId", I have to get the id in firestore

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617965/14725239), to check if a user exists you can use FirebaseAuth like this:

```
void _checkIfExsist(String email) async {
    // final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final _list = await _auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
    if(_list.isEmpty){
      //User not registered
    } else {
      //User registered
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**

As said by other user before, you need to await Future:

```
void registergoogleUser() async {
    await _userProvider
        .registergoogleUser( _scaffoldKey)
        .then((response) async {
          if (response is Success<UserCredential>) {
            // You need to await the Futures!
            Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUser(String userId) async {
              final FirebaseFirestore instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
              print (instance.collection('users')?.doc(userId)?.get()); //print for test
              return instance.collection('users')?.doc(userId)?.get();
            }
            final result = await getUser(userId);
            if (result != null) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  TopNavigationScreen.id, (route) => false);
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, RegisterScreen.id);
            }
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, hmmmm "final result = await getUser(userId);"  return error: Undefined name 'userId'.this is a lead to follow, I think I must have made a mistake in my code but I can't find it, or, that's why I put the link of my github, thanks again